# B2B Multiple warehouse management for sellers and shipping from multiple warehouses in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, multi-source-inventory, vendor, magento2-b2b

single vendor multiple warehouse concept in B2B. Like vendors, warehouses should be located in different cities.
Is there any extension available for this and any idea about this.

Multiple warehouse management for sellers and shipping from multiple warehouses.

**Example**: Asian paints have two warehouses. Warehouse A and Warehouse B
If an order is placed, I can ship from A or B.

The warehouse will have products. If I shop from that warehouse then stock gets reduced from there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[The Inventory project](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/inventory/) does all the things you want.

> Inventory Management features include
>
> - Different configurations for merchants whose inventory originates from a single source and from multiple sources
> - Stocks for tracking available aggregated quantities through assigned sources
> - Concurrent checkout protection
> - Shipment matching algorithms